# What is causing CPU spike in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-performance, azure-diagnostics

Below shows the CPU spike in a 24 hour period of one of our Azure SQL database. [compute utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNMwg.jpg)

In Query Performance, the top 5 queries by CPU in thesame 24 hour period is shown in the image below.  [query performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbAH2.jpg)

However,the number of spikes in the overview above are more frequent than the top query by CPU. Where can we find what is causing the spike beside the Query Performance since it seems to be something else altogether?

Comment: The granularity of the two charts is different. The one with the higher spikes is more granular.

Comment: Also I suggest you look at ssms to view query store data. It is more detailed than the portal

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but might be useful for others, the following query shows top 10 active CPU consuming queries in Azure:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       GETDATE() runtime,
       *
FROM
(
    SELECT query_stats.query_hash,
           SUM(query_stats.cpu_time) 'Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms',
           SUM(logical_reads) 'Total_Request_Logical_Reads',
           MIN(start_time) 'Earliest_Request_start_Time',
           COUNT(*) 'Number_Of_Requests',
           SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(MIN(query_stats.statement_text), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), 1, 256) AS "Statement_Text"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT req.*,
               SUBSTRING(   ST.text,
                            (req.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1,
                            ((CASE statement_end_offset
                                  WHEN -1 THEN
                                      DATALENGTH(ST.text)
                                  ELSE
                                      req.statement_end_offset
                              END - req.statement_start_offset
                             ) / 2
                            ) + 1
                        ) AS statement_text
        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS req
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS ST
    ) AS query_stats
    GROUP BY query_hash
) AS t
ORDER BY Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms DESC;
```